# Question Regarding Composition of Functions

Tags: functions

Here is an exercise from my textbook that I have been struggling to solve for a while now.

Suppose $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ is called good if for any function $g : Z \longrightarrow Y$ with $|Z| \leq 13$ there exists an injection $h : Z \longrightarrow X$ such that $g = f \circ h$. How can we describe the set of positive numbers $n$ for which there exists a good function $f : [1000] \longrightarrow [n]$?

I would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to show that

> $f$ is good if and only if for every $y \in Y$, the preimage $f^{-1}(y)$ has at least $13$ elements.

Proof: "If" part: let $g:Z \rightarrow Y$ be any function with $|Z| \leq 13$.

For each $y \in Y$, we have $|g^{-1}(y)|\leq 13 \leq |f^{-1}(y)|$, hence there exists an injection $h_y: g^{-1}(y) \rightarrow f^{-1}(y)$.

Since $Z$ is the disjoint union of all $g^{-1}(y)$, the $h_y$'s glue to a well-defined function $h: Z\rightarrow X$. It is easy to see that it satisfies the willing properties.

"Only if" part: if there exists $y\in Y$ such that $|f^{-1}(y)| < 13$, then the constant function $g:[13] \rightarrow Y$ sending every element to $y$ causes a problem: no possible $h$ can exist, as $|f^{-1}(y)| < |g^{-1}(y)|$.

---

From this, it is clear that

> for positive integers $m, n$, there exists a good function $f:[m]\rightarrow [n]$ if and only if $m \geq 13 n$.

And the final answer is "the set of positive integers $\leq 76$".

Comment: for the first part of the proof, why is it the case that $13 \leq |f ^ {-1}(y)|$? The first part of the inequality - $|g^ {-1}(y)| \leq 13$ - makes sense, but I don't see why the second inequality is necessarily true.

Comment: It's the assumption. I'm proving the "If" part, i.e. assuming that $|f^{-1}(y)| \geq 13$ for every $y$, we want to show that $f$ is good.

Comment: I was asking about the first part where you assume that $f$ is good, and go ahead to prove that $\forall y \in Y \; |f^{-1}(y)| \geq 13$. For the part where you say $|g^{-1}(y)| \leq 13 \leq |f^{-1}(y)|$, I don't see why $13 \leq |f^{-1}(y)| $ is true.

Comment: No, the first part is the "If" part, and $|f^{-1}(y)| \geq 13$ is the assumption. The "Only if" part is where I assume $f$ good (or rather, assume that $|f^{-1}(y)| < 13$ for some $y$, and show that $f$ is not good).

Comment: This totally makes sense! I was getting confused for no reason. Thanks:)